# ¿Porqué se llama a la variable de contexto de Android como mContext?

Tags: android

Hola a todos me gustaría saber porqué en muchos de los ejemplos donde se usa el contexto de Android se utiliza el nombre de variable como `mContext`, entiendo que es una convención pero de dónde viene el nombre o dónde puedo encontrar más documentación acerca de las convenciones de nombres para Android.

```
public void doSomething(Context context) {
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext(); 
}
```

En algún ejemplo observé `sContext` me gustaría saber porque se usan estas convenciones y que significan, gracias.

Comment: Esta notación proviene de [AOSP](https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/code-style#follow-field-naming-conventions) (Proyecto de código abierto de Android) se utiliza el prefijo `m` para los nombres de campo no públicos y no estáticos,  `s` para los nombres de campo estático, aunque la guia de estilo de java contradice el uso del prefijo [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.1-identifier-names)

Comment: Este comentario deberia ir como respuesta a la pregunta ^

Comment: @A.Palacio en pocas palabras se usa para "variables miembro", que son no públicas y no estáticas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Porqué se llama a la variable de contexto de Android como mContext?

Algunos programadores usan la "m" al inicio de una variable, para definir una "Variable miembro" ("[member variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_variable)").

> En la programación orientada a objetos, una variable miembro (a veces
>   llamada campo miembro) es una variable asociada con un objeto
>   específico y accesible para todos sus métodos (funciones miembro).
>
> **Una variable miembro es definida como privada (`private`) y no estática (`static`).**

```
private Context mContext;
private String nombre = "israteneda";

public void doSomething(Context context) {
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext(); 
}
```

El termino `variable miembro` regularmente es usado en C++, mientras que en Java se usa Campo (`field`), aunque últimamente es usado también  `variable miembro`.

---

> En algún ejemplo observé sContext me gustaría saber porque se usan
>   estas convenciones y que significan, gracias.

Las variables que inician con "s", indican de acuerdo a la convención de código Java, indican una variable estática.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int sNumero = 42;
    private static MyClass sSingleton; 
}
```

---

Por cierto en el caso del contexto **en android no es recomendable definir la variable que almacenará el contexto, como estático, ya que al requerir el sistema operativo recursos, lo primero que elimina son precisamente estas variables definidas como estáticas.**

Answer (score 0):

esto es debido a la notacion hungara

El prefijo "m" o "s" en el nombre indica un campo de instancia privado / paquete o un campo estático privado / paquete, respectivamente, donde esto no se conocería en la revisión de código. Esto supone que el campo no es visible en el cambio, ya que obviamente su visibilidad se conocería independientemente.

Antes de intentar refutar esto, definamos la notación húngara. Según Wikipedia, hay dos tipos de anotaciones húngaras:

```
La notación del sistema codificó el tipo de datos de la variable en su nombre. Una ID de usuario que estuvo representada durante mucho tiempo en Java nombraría una variable lUserId para indicar tanto la información de uso como la de tipo.
La notación de aplicaciones codificó el uso semántico de la variable en lugar del uso lógico o el propósito. Una variable para almacenar información privada tenía un prefijo (como mUserId), mientras que una variable para almacenar información pública tenía otro prefijo, o ninguno.
```

Comment: "m" no puede indicar un campo estático